# showdata function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am new in php and ajax.

When I load data without pagination code it will display properly, but when I merge two data it will not work. As per my understanding my show data function is not working.

This is my code.

`index.php`

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['deletes'])) {
    $sql=mysql_query("delete from tbl_employees where emp_id='{$_POST['id']}'");
    if($sql)
    {
        echo 'success delete';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $sql="update tbl_employees SET emp_name='{$_POST['upfname']}',
    emp_lname='{$_POST['uplname']}',
    emp_email='{$_POST['upemail']}',
    emp_phno= '{$_POST['upphno']}' where emp_id='{$_POST['upid']}'";
    $ures=  mysql_query($sql);
    if($ures)
    {
        echo "sucessupdate";
    }

}

if(isset($_POST['editvalue'])) {
    $sql="select * from tbl_employees where emp_id='{$_POST['id']}'";
    $eres=mysql_query($sql);
    $erow=  mysql_fetch_array($eres);
    header("content-type:text/x-json");
    echo json_encode($erow);
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['buttonsave'])) {
    $query="INSERT INTO tbl_employees( emp_name, emp_lname, emp_email, emp_phno) VALUES ('{$_POST['fname']}','{$_POST['lname']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['phno']}')";
    $res=  mysql_query($query);   
    if($res)
    {
        echo 'success';
    }
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['showtabledata'])) {

    $sql="select * from tbl_employees";
    $rsd=mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {

        $eid    = $row['emp_id'];
        $fname = $row['emp_name'];
        $lname    = $row['emp_lname'];
        $email  = $row['emp_email'];
        $phno=$row['emp_phno'];
        ?>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <!--<td><?php //echo $eid; ?></td>-->
                <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $phno; ?></td>
                <td><a ide=<?php echo $eid; ?> class='edit' href='#?ide=<?php echo $eid; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
                <td> <a idd=<?php echo $eid; ?> class='delete' href='#?idd=<?php echo $eid; ?>'>DELETE</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
}

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="newajax.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="pagination.js"></script>--> 

<div id="container">
    <form method="post" id="reg-form">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $erow[1] ?>" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $erow[2] ?>"required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Mail" value="<?php echo $erow[3] ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="phno" id="phno" placeholder="Contact No" value="<?php echo $erow[4] ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><hr /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><button  type="submit" id="save" name="save">Register</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><button type="submit" id="update" name="update">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <!--<th>id</th>-->
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phno</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="showdata">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

`data.php`

```
<?php
    include('dbconfig.php');
    $shw=$_POST['showdata'];
    $per_page = 3;
    if($_GET) {
        $page=$_GET['page'];
    }
    //$page=1;
    //getting table contents
    if(isset($_POST['showdata'])) {
        $start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
        $sql = "select * from tbl_employees order by emp_id limit $start,$per_page";
        $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <center>
            <table id="tbl" align="center">
                <!--<th><b>Id</b></th>-->
                <th><b>FirstName</b></th>
                <th><b>LastName</b></th>
                <th><b>Email</b></th>
                <th><b>Phno.</b></th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
                {
                    $id    = $row['emp_id'];
                    $fname = $row['emp_name'];
                    $mname    = $row['emp_lname'];
                    $lname    = $row['emp_email'];
                    $phno=$row['emp_phno'];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<td><?php// echo $id; ?></td>-->
                        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $mname; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $phno; ?></td>
                        <!--<td><?php //echo $lname; ?></td>-->
                        <td><a ide=<?php echo $id; ?> class='edit' href='#?ide=<?php echo $id; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
                        <td> <a idd=<?php echo $id; ?> class='delete' href='#?idd=<?php echo $id; ?>'>DELETE</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
    } //End while
    ?>
    </table>
    </center>
    <style>
        #tbl
        {
            width:800px;
            border:1px solid #98bf21;
            margin-top:50px;
        }
    /*#tbl tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #00a2d1
    }*/
    #tbl td{
        border:1px solid #00a2d1
    }
    #tbl th
    {
        background: #00a2d1;
        border:1px solid #00a2d1
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

`ajax.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Display_Load() {
    //$("#loading").fadeIn(100);
    //$("#loading").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' />");
    }
    //Hide Loading Image
    function Hide_Load() {
    //$("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
    };
    //Default Starting Page Results
    $("#pagination li:first").css({'color' : '#FF0084','border' : 'none'});
    $("#content").load("data.php?page= 1");
    $('#update').hide();
    $("#reg-form").validate({
        rules: {
            fname:{
                required:true
            },
            lname:{
                required:true
            },
            email:{
                required:true,             
                email:true
            },
            phno:{                      
                required:true,
                number:true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10
            },
        },
        messages: {
            fname:"please enter first name",
            lname:"plese enter your surname",
            email:"please enter valid email address",
            phno:{
                required:"please enter your phno",
                minlength:"ph no should be min 10 digit",
                maxlength:"ph no should be max 10 digit"
            }
        },
    //        //submitHandler: submit
    });   
    // $('#update').click(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#update',function(){
            $('#save').show();
            $('#update').hide();
            var eid=$('#id').val();
            var ename=$('#fname').val(); 
            var elname=$('#lname').val(); 
            var eemail=$('#email').val(); 
            var ephno=$('#phno').val(); 
            $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",
                type:"POST",
                async:false,
                data:{
                    update:1,
                    upid:eid,
                    upfname:ename,
                    uplname:elname,
                    upemail:eemail,
                    upphno:ephno
                },
                success:function(up){
                    alert("success");
                    $('input[type=text]').val('');
    //window.location.reload();
    //document.getElementById("reg-form").reset(); 
    showtabledata();
    }
    });
        });
        $('body').delegate('.delete','click',function(){
            var IDdelete=$(this).attr('idd');
            var test= window.confirm("are you sure you want to delete")
            if(test)
            {
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"index.php",
                        type:"POST",
                        async:false,
                        data:{
                            deletes:1,
                            id:IDdelete
                        },
                        success:function(){
                            alert("delete success");
                            alert(deletes);
    //window.location.reload();
    showtabledata();
    }
    });
                }
            }
        });
    // $('body').delegate('.edit','click',function(){
        $(document).on('click','.edit',function(){
            $('#save').hide();
            $('#update').show();
            var IDedit=$(this).attr('ide');
            $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",
                type:"POST",
                datatype:"JSON",
                data:{
                    editvalue:1,
                    id :IDedit
                },
                success:function(show)
                {
                    $('#id').val(show.emp_id),
                    $('#fname').val(show.emp_name);
                    $('#lname').val(show.emp_lname);
                    $('#email').val(show.emp_email);
                    $('#phno').val(show.emp_phno);
                }
            });
        });
    //  $('#save').click(function(){
        $(document).on('submit', '#reg-form', function(){
            var firstname=$('#fname').val();
            var lastname=$('#lname').val();
            var emailadd=$('#email').val();
            var phnum=$('#phno').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",
                type:"POST",
                async:false,
                data:{
                    buttonsave:1,
                    fname:firstname,
                    lname:lastname,
                    email:emailadd,
                    phno:phnum
                },
                success:function(result)
                {
                    alert("success");
                    alert(result);
                    showtabledata();
                }
            });
        });
        $("#pagination li").click(function(){
    //Display_Load();
    //CSS Styles
    $("#pagination li")
    .css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 1px'})
    .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});
    $(this)
    .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
    .css({'border' : 'none'});
    //Loading Data
    var pageNum = this.id;
    $("#content").load("data.php?page=" + pageNum);
    });
    });    
    function showtabledata()
    {
    //var showdata=1;
    $.ajax({
        url:"data.php",
        type:"POST",
        async:false,
        data:{
            showdata:1
        },
        success:function(re)
        {
    //alert(re);
    // $('#showdata').html(re);
    }
    });
    //$("#load").load("/load.php") ;
    }
```

Data doesn't display without load.

Please some give suggestion.

Comment: Indented the code, fixed the grammar.

Comment: Your js code is crazy long and has some errors (at least what linter suggest).

Comment: what is errors in js?

Comment: this code is working ..but the problem is without load data  not display.

Comment: Missing semicolons and some linter stuff